# How to change the URL of a component with a changing of its state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Well, I got an e-commerce component page, which has to change its state after clicking on some particular menu buttons, and then render some product types. I have only one component for all products categories, so with changing the state I also want to change the link in react-router. How to change the link of a component with changing the state?

So, what I did. First, I added the url parameter in state:

```
state = {
productType1: false,
productType2: false,
link: ' '
}
```

Here are the functions, which changing the state of a main component. Right here I also have a url with needed value.

```
showProductType1= () => {
this.setState(() => {
  return {
    productType1: true,
    productType2: false,
    link: '/product_type1',
  }
})
}

showProductType2= () => {
this.setState(() => {
  return {
    productType2: true,
    productType1: false,
    link: '/product_type2',
  }
})
}
```

Then I passed all these as props into the main component, which is responsible for displaying different product types.

```
<Route exact path={this.state.link} render={(props) => 
 <ProductList {...props} 
 productType1={this.state.productType1} 
 productType2={this.state.productType2}/>
 }>
</Route>
```

And the functions went to the navbar component so the state could change after clicking on specific menus.

```
<Navbar 
showProductType1 = {this.showProductType1} 
showProductType2 = {this.showProductType2} 
link={this.state.link}/>
```

Well, and everything is working, but not properly. When I click on the navbar menus, everything is changing, both state (component shows proper product types) and link, but only after I click twice on the menu button. 
After just one click nothing happens, component doesn't update, and link doesn't change. But if I click on the menu button one more time - everything starts to work, state is changing together with a needed URL.

So, how to change the displayed link of a component together with its state?
Many thanks in advance, fellow community

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). To also keep your code efficient.

For ex.

```
var link = this.state.showProductType1 ? this.state.showProductType1Link : this.state.showProductType2Link
```

Meaning that if the variable of `showProductType1` is true then it will use that link. If not true, it will take the next value being `showProductType2Link`.